# C# equivalent to List.Skip(n).Take() in Python

Tags: python

Consider this list:

```
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

In C# I can write `list.Skip(2).Take()` and it gives me this list:

```
['third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

What is the equivalent in Python? I've seen some examples on how to ommit items from the middle of the list, but that's not my case.

Comment: `my_list[2:]` but let me find a reference post for you